# php not converting json string to json array

Tags: php, json

I want this string `{"id": "23", "flag":"1", "qty": "2", "size": "23"},{"id":"12", "flag":"2", "qty":"1", "size":"12"}` to json array.

I have used following code but not working.

```
$data = '{"id": "23", "flag":"1", "qty": "2", "size": "23"},{"id":"12", "flag":"2", "qty":"1", "size":"12"';


echo json_decode($data, true);
```

If anyone know please help me how to do this.

Comment: You can't decode or encode it to a json array, because your data is not a json array. It's two separate json objects. Put `[]` around it and it will work: https://3v4l.org/KX6tm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = '[{"id": "23", "flag":"1", "qty": "2", "size": "23"},{"id":"12", "flag":"2", "qty":"1", "size":"12"}]';

echo '<pre>' . print_r(json_decode($data),true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank You! for your time

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid you should change it to this because it is a JSON array

`[{"id": "23", "flag":"1", "qty": "2", "size": "23"},{"id":"12", "flag":"2", "qty":"1", "size":"12"}]`